# findById request, cant find my data in mongodb collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am creating URL Shortener Microservice application.I have a mongodb cluster that i save my all url links. I am successfully connect to database.I am making post request to save my posted url. Related code is here

```
app.post('/api/shorturl', (req, res) => {
  const bodyUrl = req.body.url;

  const something = dns.lookup(
    urlParser.parse(bodyUrl).hostname,
    (error, address) => {
      if (!address) {
        res.json({ error: 'Invalid URL' });
      } else {
        const url = new Url({ url: bodyUrl });
        url.save((err, data) => {
          res.json({
            original_url: data.url,
            short_url: data.id,
          });
        });
      }
    }
  );
});
```

So, I can save my new url in database succesfully.Here also related cluster after post request[image]
But my problem is with get request. I dont know why i cant find the url links by id. Here also my get request

```
app.get('/api/shorturl/:id', (req, res) => {
  // const id = req.body.id;
  Url.findById({ _id: req.body.id }, (err, data) => {
    if (!data) {
      res.json({ error: 'Invalid URL' });
    } else {
      res.redirect(data.url);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either use:

```
  Url.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, data) => {
    if (!data) {
      res.json({ error: 'Invalid URL' });
    } else {
      res.redirect(data.url);
    }
  });
```

or:

```
  Url.findById(req.params.id, (err, data) => {
    if (!data) {
      res.json({ error: 'Invalid URL' });
    } else {
      res.redirect(data.url);
    }
  });
```

`findOne` takes an object as the argument (like you have).

`findById` just takes the ID as the argument.

You seem to be combining the two options.

Edit: I found another issue with your code, you are trying to pull the id from `req.body.id`, but in this case, you need to use `req.params.id`. The code in my post has been updated.

Comment: Actually still cant find after your suggestion. look https://url-shortener12.herokuapp.com/. I am adding short_url at the end of the link, but it not redirect me to the link that i posted

Comment: What is the value that you send as the :id parameter in your GET request? Are you putting the URL there? or the mongodb ID?

edit: Nvm I see what you are doing. Not sure what's wrong. Can you post your updated code?

Comment: I think I figured out the issue. Take a look at the edit at the end of my post. Code has also been updated.